# Shopware 6 App - Individual text fields in config for each storefront (translatable)

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

When i change the text in one storefront the text is also changed in the other storefront (cause its the same snippet).

This is my snippet:

```xml
<component name="sw-snippet-field">
    <name>leftBoxTitle</name>
    <label>Title</label>
    <label lang="de-DE">Titel</label>
    <snippet>minds-atcch.leftBoxTitle</snippet>
</component>
```

**How it is possible to create a snippet (or custom input field) for each storefront individually that is translatable?**

Answer (score 0):

If one and the same snippet should resolve to different content you'll have to create a separate snippet set. One snippet set may inherit the contents of another so you may have two sales channels assigned to two different snippet sets. One of the snippet sets may inherit all of its snippets from the original except for those snippets that you want to be different in the corresponding storefront.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73907195/two-shopware-6-sales-channel-with-same-language-how-to-separate) for a few more details.

As for the component `sw-snippet-field` it detects which snippet set to use from the current language of the API context. Changing the sales channel in the dropdown on top of the form will not change the language though. So this component will probably still not behave the way you intend it to. You could [create a custom component](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/add-custom-component) which extends `sw-snippet-field` but overrides the method where the snippet set is [retrieved by the current locale](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/app/component/form/sw-snippet-field/index.js#L119) and instead uses the selected sales channel to determine which set should be used.

Comment: Is it posssible to also select a snippet with a select box? custom components dont work in shopware 6 apps only in plugins right?

Comment: Yes custom admin components currently can only be defined with on-prem plugins. Afaik there is no component for simply selecting a snippet. You could try a `sw-entity-single-select` with the `entity` set to `snippet` but this will only display snippets sourced from the database, not all snippets from a set.